# Count swap permutations

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

Given an array A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]:

```
How many sequences (S1) can you get after exact k adjacent swaps on A?
How many sequences (S2) can you get after at most k swaps on A?
```

An adjacent swap can be made between two elements of the Array A, A[i] and A[i+1] or A[i] and A[i-1].

A swap otherwise can be between any two elements of the array A[i] and A[j] ∀ 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N, i ≠ j.

So, I need to find S1 and S2.

Example : We are given N=3 and k=2 then here S1=3 and S2=6

Explanation :

Original array: [1, 2, 3]

1. After 2 adjacent swaps:
   We can get [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2] ==> S1 == 3
2. After at most 2 swaps:

   1) After 0 swap: [1, 2, 3]

   2) After 1 swap: [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2].

   3) After 2 swaps: [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]
   ==> S2 == 6

Comment: ONGOING CONTEST Problem ,Hold the question : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w5/challenges/swappermutation