# Number of distinct Arrays formed from swapping pairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given an Array $A$ as a permutation of first $N$ natural numbers and an integer $m$, how can we find the number of distinct arrays that we can generate from $A$ by performing exactly $m$ swap operations.
Eg : $A =\{1,2,3\}$  and $m=1$
Then possible resulting arrays can be $\{2,1,3\}, \{1,3,2\}, \{3,2,1\}$.  So answer is $3$.

Comment: There are $\binom{N}{2}$ ways of performing a swap, for any given swap, and $N!$ possible permutations in total... perhaps one could use inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Let $x=C(n,2)$ For $k$ swaps, you have $C(x,k)$ ways to select swaps, then $k!$ ways to perform these swaps.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate but also unanswered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839884/count-swap-permutations)

Here's a piece of c++ code i just wrote to help find and answer to this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, m;
    cout << "Enter number of distinct numbers in array: ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> startNumbers;
    startNumbers.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i)
        startNumbers.push_back(i);
    vector<vector<int>> permutations;
    permutations.push_back(startNumbers);
    cout << "Enter number of swaps: ";
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        vector<vector<int>> newPermutations;
        newPermutations.reserve(n*permutations.size());
        for (auto vec : permutations){
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
                for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
                    if (j != k){
                        auto tempVec = vec;
                        iter_swap(tempVec.begin() + j, tempVec.begin() + k);
                        newPermutations.push_back(tempVec);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        sort(newPermutations.begin(), newPermutations.end());
        newPermutations.erase(unique(newPermutations.begin(), newPermutations.end()), newPermutations.end());
        newPermutations.shrink_to_fit();
        permutations = newPermutations;
    }
    cout <<"Number of distinct arrays: " << permutations.size() <<"\n";
    cout << "Distinct arrays: ";
    for (auto& p : permutations){
        cout << "[ ";
        for (auto& n : p){
            cout << n << " ";
        }
        cout << "] ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Notice this gets slow really fast.

Things to note for $N =$ numbers in array, $m =$ number of swaps:

- maximum number of distinct arrays seems to be $\frac{N!}{2}$ and is reached at $m = N-2$ and stays at that value for bigger $m \geq N-2$
- [the corresponding OEIS-sequence](https://oeis.org/A087644)

By checking out [the paper mentioned in the OEIS article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.366.4340&rep=rep1&type=pdf), you can find that the formula for calculating the number of half of the linearly inducible orderings of points in d-space is (Quote):

> $$\frac{Q(n, d)}{2}= \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \hspace{2pt}{}_{n}S_{k} = 1 + \sum_{2 \leq i \leq >d-1}{i} + \sum_{2 \leq i \leq j \leq d-1}ij + \text{ }... \text{ (d Terms)}$$
>
> where ${}_{n}S_{k}$ is the sum of the possible products of numbers taken k at a time without repetition from the set $\{2, 3, ... ,n - 1 \}$.

I wrote a short program to calculate that formula:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int nSk(int n, int k){
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    if (k > n-2)
        return 0;
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(n - 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i){
        numbers.push_back(i + 2);
    }


    std::vector<bool> v(numbers.size());
    std::fill(v.end() - k, v.end(), true);
    int ret = 0;
    do {
        int tmpnum = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {
            if (v[j])
            {
                tmpnum *= numbers[j];
            }
        }
        ret += tmpnum;
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    int n, d;
    cout << "enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "ender d: ";
    cin >> d;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k){
        sum += nSk(n, k);
    }
    //sum *= 2;
    cout << "Q(n, d) =  "<< sum << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Entering $n=$ number of arrays and $d=$ number of swaps $+ 1$ gives you what you are looking for.

I have not figured out yet why the number of distinct arrays which can be formed by swapping exactly m times is related to the number of linearly inducible orderings of n points in d-space precisely, but will update as soon as i do.

Comment: Let $f(n,m)$ be the number of permutations of that can be obtained by exactly $m$ transpositions. Then $f(n+1,m)=f(n,m)+nf(n,m-1)$: there are $f(n,m)$ permutations that can be obtained by transpositions not involving $n+1$, and there are $nf(n,m-1)$ that can be obtained by applying $m-1$ transpositions to $12\ldots n$ and then one transposition interchanging $n+1$ and the desired last element. This is the same recurrence as the one for $Q(n,d)$, but where that has initial conditions $Q(n,1)=2$ for $n\ge 2$ and $Q(2,d)=2$ for $d\ge 1$, this one has $f(n,0)=1$ for $n\ge 1$ and ...

Comment: ... $f(2,m)=1$ for $m\ge 0$. It follows immediately that $f(n,m)=\frac12Q(n,m+1)$.